# the token expires when I generate another token wso2 apim 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have downloaded APIM 4.0.0.0 and update wso2am-4.0.0.84

When I generate my first token and consume an API it generates 200 ok, but when I generate another token, it immediately expires the first token generated, i.e. when I generate a new token the previous one expires.

only happens in update 4.0.xxx but in other versions even in 4.2.0 the tokens are still alive until they expire.

Comment: To update you must execute the following lines:

./wso2update_linux current-state
./wso2update_linux check
./wso2update_linux

You must be registered on the wso2 platforms because it will ask for an email and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this line in deployment.toml

```
[oauth.access_token]
invoke_token_revocation_event_on_renewal = false
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved in this way:
1- Update to wso2am-4.0.0.273.
2- Add the following line in the deployment.toml:

```
[oauth.jwt.renew_token_without_revoking_existing]
enable = true
```